# Is this a clojure.core.match bug or it's just me?

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, clojure-core.match

```
(match
   [[1 2 3]]
   [(:or [_ _ 2] 
         [3 _ _])] :a0

   [(:or [_ _ 1] 
         [1 _ _])] :a1
   :else :else)

=> :else
```

In this first snippet I expected it to return `:a1`.

Weird.

This works:

```
(match
   [[1 2 3]]
   [(:or [_ _ 2] 
         [1 _ _])] :a0

   [(:or [_ _ 1] 
         [3 _ _])] :a1
   :else :else)

=> :a0
```

Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in `specialize-or-pattern-row`. I believe the `groupable?` test there is wrong because, in your case, it succeeds for your two `OrPattern`s, and so the second `OrPattern` is replaced with the expansion of the first (the `ps` are the subpatterns of the first `OrPattern`).

You could work around this by adding a dummy pattern to your second `:or` which will force `groupable?` to return false:

```
(match
   [[1 2 3]]
   [(:or [_ _ 2] 
         [1 _ _])] :a0

   [(:or [_ _ 1] 
         [3 _ _]
         :dummy)] :a1
   :else :else)
```

A possibly better `specialize-or-pattern-row` (`copy-as` is there to preserve any `:as` metadata on the overall `OrPattern` by copying the `:as` on to each of the subpatterns):

```
(defn copy-as [dest src]
  (if-let [as (-> src meta :as)]
    (vary-meta dest assoc :as as)
    dest))

(defn specialize-or-pattern-row [row pat ps]
  (let [p (first row)]
    (if (identical? p pat)
      (map (fn [p] (update-pattern row 0 (copy-as p pat))) ps)
      [row])))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it is not because the way you are using `:or` is never mentioned in the manual. It is supposed to be used in expressions like that:

```
[4 (:or 5 6 7) _] :a1
```

So your code should rather look like

```
(match
         [[1 2 3]]
         [[_ _ 2]] :a0
         [[3 _ _]] :a0

         [[_ _ 1]] :a1
         [[1 _ _]] :a1
         :else :else)
```

But just maybe you should consult with the author. It is difficult to say what was the original intention.

Comment: This was a very interesting question, and I came to the same conclusion as you. The documentation is not explicit of the intent regarding :or but it appears to only work with scalar values.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting an [answer from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/697l1i/is_this_a_clojurecorematch_bug_or_its_just_me/):

> Seems like a bug in core.match. I used a slightly simpler statement that has the same problem.

```
(match
 [[1]]
 [(:or [3] [])] :a0
 [(:or [1] [])] :a1
 :else :else)
```

> This also returns :else. I ran it through macroexpand and extracted the logic. It turns into something like this.

```
(let
 [x [1]]
  (cond (and (vector? x) (== (count x) 1) (= (nth x 0)  3)) :a0
        (and (vector? x) (== (count x) 0)) :a0
        (and (vector? x) (== (count x) 1) (= (nth x 0) 3)) :a1
        (and (vector? x) (== (count x) 0)) :a1))
```

> On the 5th line there you can see the error, it is 3 instead of 1. For some reason it takes the value that is in the first :or pattern instead of the second rows value.

Seems that this [patch](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/MATCH-122) resolves the problem.

Thanks you all!

P.S.: I haven't tested the patch, though.